# Animation - water flowing from tap - CSS3 or jQuery or GIF

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, animated-gif

I want to develop this animation as shown in the image below, where this pump is an static image and I want the water to flow out of this as shown in the drops and in the direction shown, upon a click of other element.
Whether this can be achieved through css3 Or jquery Or would I need a gif for this. Would appreciate any pointers on how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in my opinion jQuery is better option.
create 2 or 3 set of images of water drops and use that image in setInterval() to rotate through those images to get the water drop effect.

```
var index = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    switch(index){
        case 0:
            $("#waterDrop").css("background-image","url('http://s24.postimg.org/fsfk2due9/image.png')");
            index = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            $("#waterDrop").css("background-image","url('http://s24.postimg.org/v5lcqdeld/image.png')");
            index = 0;
            break;
    }
},200);
```

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fEWf7/3/)

Comment: That's great, I really like the way you thought about this. It would suffice for me, unless I get any better idea with css3 or anything else. Thanks a lot.